# When playing ice hockey and giving a pass at the blue line, who should go first?

Tags: ice-hockey, strategy

I didin't know how to clearly express my question, so here are a few explanation.

I'm currently playing in a small hockey club at a quite low level, and we always do this exercise where all the players are at one end of the rink (where the pucks are on the picture). One player on each side rushes to the blue line, only one having the puck. Then, each one crosses the other one behind the blue line, and the one who holds the puck gives it to the other one. Then, they enter the zone and shoot on the goalie. This exercise takes place on only one half of the rink. We often do this at warmup before a play.

So, my question is : which one of the two guys should be the closest to the attack zone when crossing the other one? The puck holder? The receiver?

On the picture, should 1 give it to 2 and wait a bit to avoid an offside, or should 2 give it to 1 for him to enter the zone quickly?

When we play, some say option #1, others say option #2, and it ends up in big "hugs" at the blue line, when we bump into each other. ;)

[image]

Sorry for my poor english...

Answer (score 3):

I do this drill all the time in my hockey league.

If you think about a normal NHL style break out, the center usually takes the puck up ice, breaks the offensive zone, and then passes the puck to the trailing / waiting winger.

This exercise (though only being half the rink) is simulating that same play I mentioned above. It is simulating the center (in your case the player with the puck) entering the zone and passing it immediately to the winger (in your case the player without the puck).

Since this is simulating the well known "breakout" in hockey where the center skates in, breaks into the offensive zone and then passes the puck, in your scenario...

1. The person with the puck should cross over and enter the zone first
2. The center should then pass the puck to the trailing winger
3. The center should then rush the net
4. The winger should either shoot the puck or look for a cross crease pass directed towards the center (Not in your scenario but maybe something to take up with your coach)